# Position of my UIButton are varying for in all simulator

Tags: ios, uibutton, frame

I am under one project.In that I created one uibutton at bottom of my viewcontroller using code (Not via storyboard).But when i run my app,my uibutton are placing in differents positions.for example in iphone 5,6 simulator are in some  position.In 4s,ipad simulator my uibutton is unvisible.Also i check with my own device(iphone 6) ,in that also my uibutton is not able to see.

**Needed**

I used below code for creating & placing my button position.but its not fit in one position.

```
 CGFloat buttonSize = 40;

    UIButton * disButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    disButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"23"];
    [disButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    disButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 523, 40, 40);
    [overlayView addSubview:disButton];
    [disButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPopUpViewController)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In my code i use to place position in this line:

```
disButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 523, 40, 40);

=> x-position = 150

=> Y-position = 523
```

Kindly please give some code solution for this problem.

Comment: you have to adapt the position by using `UIScreen`   exemple  : `disButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 200, 40, 40);`

Comment: i have used your code.but i got error like this.I am new to ios .did i need to do any other  code for this `Called object type 'UIScreen * _Nonnull' is not a function or function pointer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per all comments about your question.You need to set constraint for your `UIButon`.Use only `centre x,centre y` because that will helpfull to see your layout in all devices. And there is a already solution for your problem.see these below links for setting auto layout for `UIButton`

[Link 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_auto_layouts.htm)

[Link 2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Code)

[Link 3](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code)

Sure this will help you !